# Will using !# Ajax crawling on non-JS accessible site generate duplicate content on search engines?

Tags: ajax, seo, web-crawler, duplicate-content

I have a website that works with both JS on and off. All links on the page are in regular format of the form `<a href="/pagename">`but if a visitor reaches it with JS available they will be modified into `<a href="#/pagename">` and handled using hahshchange event.

This results in 2 possible URLs pointing to same content (`www.site.com/pagename` and `www.site.com/#/pagename`).

**Note:** If you reach `www.site.com/pagename` with JS on you will be automaticaly redirected to `www.site.com/#/pagename`

Now I'm wondering if I should implement the hashbang format (`www.site.com/#!/pagename`) or not since I don't know if this will result in duplicate content when crawled by bots? Google's FAQ wasn't of much help on this specific subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *probably* will cause duplicate content issues but it's hard to say for sure since crawlable ajax is a new thing. But you can easily solve this by using [canonical URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

Comment: Ah, thanks for that link, I wasn't really sure what canonical URLs are before. Even without considering crawling this helps a lot since I can't really provide a reliable fallback for reaching the AJAX-ified URL if JS is disabled.